# Buck converter output current

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, components, step-down

I need to power an Arduino and four 4.5v-9v 2A Li-ion charger boards with a single wall adapter. Not wanting a shared circuit between the chargers, I'm thinking maybe a 12v 600mA (or something..) plug with a buck converter for each charger and powering the Arduino directly from the plug.
I have no clue how to calculate how much amperage the buck converter will output given the input/output voltage range possible.
[This one](https://www.ebay.ie/itm/1x-LM2596-DC-DC-Buck-adjustable-step-down-Power-Supply-Converter-Module-Pro-New/112655241447?hash=item1a3ac690e7:g:NO4AAOSwGwlZ7VJI) states it only ouputs 1A when stepped down to 5v from 12v

Need each charger circuit to have 2A available whenever needed but cant figure out which buck converter/voltages/input current I need?

Im not fussed about exact voltages once its within range of the Ardunio (5v-12v) and chargers (4.5v-9v) of course.

Edit: 
According to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/104276/what-would-be-the-input-current-of-buck-regulator) and taking into consideration 80% efficiency, it seems my application would need a 12v plug that delivers at least 1.04A for a buck converter to step down to 5v 2A output.
Does this seem correct?
If it is then I guess the only question left is will any old buck converter that is rated for 2Amp or more be suitable?

[image: sketch up]

Comment: Are you sure your wall charger is able to deliver the required 40+ Watts for your worst case scenario? Does the buck need to be integrated or could you work with a chip and build the circuit yourself?

Comment: I have no idea how much wattage they can handle. I can build some kind of a circuit on a breadboard but Id need detailed instructions for such a job. My talent pretty much ends at drop in breakout boards and such. If i was to (hypothetically) use a fast phone charger (1.67A @ 9v or 1.25A @12v) what most likely happen?

Comment: Your supply voltage will not be stable. And your assumption that you need only 1.04A @12V is only correct if you just operate one charger at a time. Voltage may be used for parallel devices, but your current splits up into the different paths and therefore you ned 4 times the current one buck converter needs to provide 5V@2A. You would need something like this http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576hv.pdf but still your wall charger needs to be something like 12V@4A

Comment: okay then, how about a laptop charger @ 19.5v, 3.33A. Would i be right in saying that my system would have nearly 1A of headroom

Comment: Yes as 19.5V*3.3A = 64.35W and 4*5V*2A = 40W you have approximately 24W input power left (assuming the arduino's consuptions is negligible)

Comment: Awesome! So thats sorted. Regarding the buck converter to choose you recommend something with the LM2576HV over the LM2596 then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it only makes 1A

No, It can output 3A with carefully heatsinking.

> I have no clue how to calculate how much amperage the buck converter will make

"will make " or "will consume "?

Here is the graph showing efficiency vs input voltage :

[image]

As you can see, the efficiency is about 80 % if input voltage is 12V. 
The only problem is if your 12 V adapter can provide enough wattage for your load.

Comment: so the ebay listing is incorrect, it in fact will make 3A once thermals allow? Also when i said 'make' i meant be able to output, my bad. I assume the graph is from the LM2596 from what i linked to above?

Comment: what do you think of a laptop charger @ 19.5v, 3.33A. Handles 65W so maybe good for the job?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: "do you think " is enough, not "what do you think" :)